# Loopback 4: how to import ValidationError?

Tags: validation, loopback4

A simple question.

Their documentation is outdated. I wanna make the interceptor following the tutorial on this page:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Validation-controller-repo-service-layer.html

However the example code doesn't work:

```
async intercept(
  invocationCtx: InvocationContext,
  next: () => ValueOrPromise<InvocationResult>,
) {
  // Add pre-invocation logic here
  // ------ VALIDATE PHONE NUMBER ----------
  let coffeeShop: CoffeeShop | undefined;
  if (invocationCtx.methodName === 'create')
    coffeeShop = invocationCtx.args[0];
  else if (invocationCtx.methodName === 'updateById')
    coffeeShop = invocationCtx.args[1];

  if (
    coffeeShop &&
    !this.isAreaCodeValid(coffeeShop.phoneNum, coffeeShop.city)
  ) {
    const err: ValidationError = new ValidationError(
      'Area code and city do not match',
    );
    err.statusCode = 422;
    throw err;
  }
  // ----------------------------------------

  const result = await next();
  // Add post-invocation logic here
  return result;
  } catch (err) {
    // Add error handling logic here
    throw err;
  }
}

isAreaCodeValid(phoneNum: string, city: string): Boolean {
 ...
}
```

because ValidationError is unknown. I can't find it anywhere, where can I import it from?

```
 const err: ValidationError = new ValidationError(
      'Area code and city do not match',
    );
```

And if ValidationError is deprecated and it shouldn't be used anymore, then what should I do when I wanna throw a 422 validation error?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the soolution is in one of the examples apps (validation app).

Anyway, all you need is to export this class:

```
class ValidationError extends Error {
  code?: string;
  statusCode?: number;
}
```

It is not exported by the core framework. Maybe the docs should be updated.